# How can I split a string at the first occurrence of "-" (minus sign) into two $vars with PHP?

Tags: php, split

How can I split a string at the first occurrence of - (minus sign) into two $vars with PHP?

I have found how to split on every "-" but, not only on the first occurrence.

example:

```
this - is - line - of whatever - is - relevant
$var1 = this
$var2 = is - line - of whatever - is - relevant
```

Note, also stripped the first "-" .

Answer (score 187):

It's very simple, using an extra paramater to `explode` that many people don't realize is there:

`list($before, $after) = explode('-', $source, 2);`

Comment: That is cool. So then I 

$fixed_string = str_replace("-", "  ", $before); to get rid of the - ?

Comment: No, the first `-` will be removed as part of the `explode()` function.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs. I was wondering that if I added a $middle then explode - source 3 ?? Would that work or should I use array[x] as mentioned by Brad?

Comment: @Jimbo if this solution worked for you mark this as such so others can find it easier. Thanks! :)

Comment: To trim the variables in list, use : list($before, $after) = array_map('trim',explode('-', $source, 2));

Answer (score 63):

```
$array = explode('-', 'some-string', 2);
```

Then you could do `$var1=$array[0]` and `$var2=$array[1]`.

Comment: Thanks Brad, this will also be useful. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) function:

```
$first = strtok($string, '-');
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need: using list() with explode():

```
list($var1, $var2) = explode(' - ', 'this - is - line - of whatever - is - relevant', 2);
```

Note the spaces around the "-" (minus sign)

Comment: list($var1, $var2) = array_map('trim',explode('-', 'this - is - line - of whatever - is - relevant', 2)); so you don't need to take care of the spaces and $var1 and $var2 are trimmed