# php if array contains this variable

Tags: php, arrays

Array `stdt` contains numerical value with following structure.

**Array stdt**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3-65
    [1] => 4-35
)
```

Let divide, this array as : before hyphen: **first part** and after hyphen: **second part**

Now, I want to compare this array `$stdt` to another variable `$number`.

**I want to**

If variable `$number` matches with any index's **first part**, then echo the number after `hyphen -` of matched index.

```
$number = '3';

$stdt = ["3-45", "4-35"];
```

Here, echoed value must be 45, because variable matched with first index. I am trying with following if condition, but can't conclude to expected result

```
if (stripos(json_encode($stdt), $number) !== false) {
    echo "index number after hyphen"; //but how to split array and echo number after hyphen
}
```

Comment: Use explode() inside foreach()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split a string at the first occurrence of "-" (minus sign) into two $vars with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507901/how-can-i-split-a-string-at-the-first-occurrence-of-minus-sign-into-two-v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial question:

> if variable $number matches with any index's first part, then echo the number after hyphen - of matched index.

To solve it, here are some less-optimized codes for you to learn from step to step:

```
$number = '3';
$stdt = ["3-45", "4-35"];
// loop through the array $stdt
foreach($stdt as $val) {
    // explode() is to separate the string with specific delimiter
    // in the first item in the array, $tokens[0] is 3, $tokens[1] is 45
    $tokens = explode('-', $val); 
    if($tokens[0] == $number) { // if we got a match...
        echo $tokens[1];
        break; // ...break the loop, end the process
    }
}
```

This code assumes you want to return 1 value only. If you want to extract all value that starts with `3-`, you can remove the `break;` line.

From the codes in your answer, you shouldn't use `json_encode()`, as it's not a JSON string; also for `stripos()`, it is inappropriate to use in this case, as the character `3` might appear elsewhere (e.g. on the second part of the hyphenated string).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Easily understanding and optimized way. +1 for detecting my mistakes. Thanks man !!!

Answer (score 1):

Simple, here you go

```
$number='3';

$stdt= ["3-45", "4-35"];

array_map(function($item)use($number){if(0===strpos($item,$number.'-'))echo substr($item,strlen($number.'-'))."\n";},$stdt);
```

Output

```
45
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0536a6fad0c6c189835a7387187d1254fa6e1515)

**UPDATE1**

I thought about "golfing" it ... ha ha (**97 bytes** 92 without the newline).

```
$n='3';

$a= ["3-45", "4-35"];

array_map(function($i)use($n){$n.='-';echo 0===strpos($i,$n)?substr($i,strlen($n))."\n":'';},$a);
```

[Smallifed Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d92487157be60c31dea04b7adf855a32a0e379d2)

It even correctly accounts for things like

```
$number = 3;
//where 33 could be matched by "false !== strpos($i,$n)"
$stdt= ["3-45", "4-35", "33-99"];
```

I will explain the smallified version as its more complex.

1. `array_map` walks though an array and applies a callback function, you can think of it like a loop.

   - in this case its a user supplied closure, with the input if `$i`
   - we need the number `$n` in so we pass it in by using `use($n)`
2. foreach loop, we append the `-` to the number.  `$n=3` becomes `$n='3-'`

   - this just shortens things for us latter on
3. we use a shorthand "ternary" if statement it takes the from of

   - `condition ? if true : if false;`
   - `strpos` - check the position of one string in another and returns it
   - in this case we want to check if `$n='3-'` is `0` or the first position (0 based index)
   - by adding the `-` to the number we can be sure it doesn't match things like `$i='33-'`.  For example `3-` does not match `33-` but `3` can.
   - we use `===` strict type checking because `strpos` returns boolean `false` if it's not in the string and `false == 0` is true, but `false === 0` is not because they are different types.
4. [IF TRUE] then we basically remove `$n` from `$i`.

   - we can use the length of `$n` which is `$n='3-'` or 2 to get the start position for sub string.  So we could write it like `substr('3-45', 2)` but because `$n` can be anything, it's better to measure it
5. [IF false] we just return an empty string which gets returned to echo.

Expanded Version Of Code:

```
 array_map(
     function( $i ) use ( $n ){
         $n .= '-';
         echo (0 === strpos( $i, $n ) ) ? substr( $i, strlen( $n ) ) : '';
     },
 $a);
```

**Difference between 1 & 2**

The first version is basically the same, but I realized I could shorten it by adding the `-` on to the number before hand instead of appending it twice.

The major differences are

- shortened the variables to 1 letter (just to save space)
- Using ternary instead of a normal `if` statement

**UPDATE2**

Last thing I will do is write a Bigger more normal looking version:

```
$number = 3;
$stdt= ["3-45", "4-35", "33-99", '3-33'];

//makes life easier, also solves some issues by converting number to a string.
//We set it outside the loop for performance, we could add it with . every time but that's just waste.
$n = $number .'-';
//length of n
$l = strlen($n);
foreach($stdt AS $st){
    //find the position of $n, 0 = first, false = not found
    //again === strict type chcking
    if(0 === ($pos = strpos($st, $n))){
        //use the length of $n (one of those makes life easier things)
        //here we can use substr its much safer then trim.
        echo substr($st, $l))."\n";
    }

}
```

[Bigified Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ddf790dae7e6ac01381173eaaa6f3fc9882005a7)

There is probably a million ways you can do this.  I did the above because it gets boring so it's fun to try to make it as small and short as possible.

Cheers!

:-p - thanks for the fun!

*PS* I got rid of the one with trim, it's to problematic and hard to explain when they remove stuff in different ways.  Now they are are roughly equivalent.

Comment: I think you might want to explain your code to OP, as OP seems a little bit inexperienced in PHP. Also, the one-liner code is hard to read, though it can give the expected output.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Highly appreciated your explanation, becomes easy to get more knowledge

Comment: Sure, I get bored with plain old `foreach` there is actually a stack exchange section called "Code Golf" that is basically a game to write the smallest program possible.  It's actually kind of hard with PHP, although I've done a few interesting ones on there.

Comment: **Code Golf**, hadn't idea about the topic, recently read and visit about this, shortest->+1. Really worthy to follow, once again Thanks man ! for new information !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
<?php

$number = '3';
$stdt = ["3-45", "4-35"];

foreach ($stdt as $item) {
    [$index, $value] = explode('-', $item);

    if ($index === $number) {
        echo $value . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This example require php 7.1 in order to use Symmetric array destructuring you can read about it in this link http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring

Comment: In previous php versions you could try `list($index, $value) = explode('-', $item);` insted of `[$index, $value] = explode('-', $item);` You can read about list in this url http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php